# Bootstrap hamburger menu isn't working on phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, hamburger-menu

I have tried to find the issue, but nothing works for me.

If I am resizing the browser the hamburger menu wil pop up and work, but when I take a look on my phone it doesn't work. 
Did I really do something wrong?

The code I am using:

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Roy van Eerden</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#about">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#experience">Over</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can see it live at: [www.royvaneerden.com/](http://www.royvaneerden.com)

Screenshot of the phone example:
[image: Phone example]

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: @AnkithAmtange you have solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Place jquery.js above bootstrap.min.js

also, add meta in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

Check here

[image]

Answer (score 3):

just add this meta tag in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the whole html part, please replace what you have with the nav from here(w3school Documentation).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

or by checking the link [Collapse Menu Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h)